# Using Backbone.Notifier to display custom view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am using [Backbone.Notifier](http://backbone-notifier.e-w.co.il/) for showing alerts. How could I display custom backbone view inside it?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think it's suited to adding your own custom view. Customization of the notifications view comes through CSS.

For customising buttons you can use the css property :

```
buttons: [
    {'data-role': 'myOk', text: 'Sure', 'class': 'default', css: {width: 120}},
    {'data-role': 'myOk', text: 'Yes'}]
```

For customising the base notification window use the 'notifier' CSS class.

You can change this with the 'baseCls' property on the notifier.

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way of assigning a Backbone view to the notifier but if it's just customization of the aesthetics you want then hopefully the CSS is enough.

If you really wanted to go for a hacky approach you could use the NotificationView which is a standard Backbone View (part of the Notifier class - Backbone.Notifier.NotificationView). You could try overriding this to your implementation but it's definitely a hack so wouldn't recommend it. It's worth taking a look at the notifer.js source code.

Comment: i wanted to remove bootbox plugin from my app which i currently use to show custom view and completely use backbone notifier.I know there is no option to pass this plugin a view.Any hack i can do in plugin to achieve this functionality

Comment: Within the Notifier class there is the NotificationView which is a standard Backbone View you could try overriding this to your implementation but it's definitely a hack and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I'll add the commment to the answer it's worth checking out the notifier.js source code.

Answer (score 0):

To show my custom view inside backbone.notifier i am adding following lines inside the plugin

In notify function before the return statement

```
    .......

    if(options.custView){
        msgInner.off('click'); //the turn off default behaviour which is to destroy view on click
        options.custView.destroyNotifier = removeFn; //now in the custom view i just call this.destroyNotification to destroy the notification 
        msgView.$el.find('.notifier-message').html(options.custView.render().el); //pasting my view on notification to display  
    }                   
    return msgView;
}
```

This is how I now call the plugin

```
var notifier = new Backbone.Notifier({
            el : 'body',
            theme : 'clean'
        });

notifier.notify({
    custView : (new SomeView({
          x : 'xyz'
        })),
    ms : false,  //to aviod a timeout 
    destroy : true 
})
```

Comment: I don't seem to have any problem using it .Any feedback or any better way to do it